# What do the args for Gutenberg subpackage "hooks" function "doAction" mean?

Tags: javascript, hooks, block-editor

The package is supposed to mime WP's own actions system:

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/hooks

I've installed it locally and loaded up all of its modules, unfortunately, I seriously don't understand what the `functionName` and `callback` are in the case of `addAction`.

I tried messing with it quite a bit but no success. I thought `functionName` is the function I'm hooking to an action, for example:

```
var actions_api = createHooks();
function testFunction( a ) {
    console.log(a);
}
actions_api.addAction( 'testHook', 'global', 'testFunction', function( a ) {
    console.log(a);
}, 10 );
actions_api.doAction( 'testHook', 'super_arg' );
```

Returns the error `The hook callback must be a function.`, while the code above seems stupid, I tried to mess with it a bit but no success.

What am I missing? In theory, there shouldn't be a need for a callback for an action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to take a look at the [tests file](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/hooks/src/test/index.test.js) to see different ways of using hooks.

They work similarly to PHP hooks, you can set several addAction and then one doAction with the name of the hook and other arguments.

The first argument of doAction has to be the action name. Then you can pass as many arguments as you want and those will pass to the addAction callback function:

```
const myFunction = ( arg1, arg2 ) => {
    console.log( arg1, arg2 ); // Should output 'Hello' 'Hola'
};

wp.hooks.addAction( 'action_name', 'function_name', myFunction );

wp.hooks.doAction( 'action_name', 'Hello', 'Hola' );
```

The first argument is the hook name. Several `addAction` (or `addFilter`) can hook into the given hook by its name and all will be executed when calling `doAction` (or `applyFilters`).
The second argument identifies the action or filter (`addAction` or `addFilter`). This is used, for example, if you want to remove one of the actions or filters. This is an adapted example taken from one of the tests:

```
const { addFilter, removeFilter, applyFilters } = wp.hooks;

function filterA(str) {
    return str + "A";
}

function filterB(str) {
    return str + "B";
}

function filterC(str) {
    return str + "C";
}

addFilter("test.filter", "my_callback_filter_a", filterA);
addFilter("test.filter", "my_callback_filter_b", filterB);
addFilter("test.filter", "my_callback_filter_c", filterC);

removeFilter("test.filter", "my_callback_filter_b");

console.log(applyFilters("test.filter", "test_")); // Should output test_AC
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting looking at tests files. The tests files in general are often "forgotten" documentation :-)

Comment: That's exactly my trouble here! What could that `function_name` be?

Comment: @coolpasta I just figured out about it looking at tests. Please check the updated answer.