# How to bridge the gap between dynamic back-end data and front-end output?

Tags: filters, javascript

I wish to allow people to extend my system in any way they want while maintaining its integrity. For example, I have a component in my plugin called `Notifications`. These notifications are output to the front-end when the user clicks a small button.

Here's the thing. For the back-end, I have my API, as well as `apply_filters` so that people can add / remove their content from my output and so on...but...assuming my front-end script goes to see that data (dynamic, remember, any key can exist with any type of content) like this:

`for(let key in dataPassedFromLocalizingScript)`, there is no `do_action` for JS.

What I'm saying is, even if I provide additional data from the back-end, the front-end doesn't really know it's there or has no way of hooking inside that `for`, there's no concise API like WordPress' `$wp_filter` to be able to work with that data because **your JS script code never changes.** Sure, I can do `dispatchEvent` but it'll be very, very ugly.

How can I fix this? How can I make sense of that extendability I have in the back-end when dealing with views that use that data to build markup?

A crude example of this would be the main `main.js` script looking for a specific key `notifications` from the data that was localized **from the back-end and is where the DOM insertions happen**. Now, in this data, there might be another key `buttons` which a developer has added to be passed down but unfortunately, the DOM inserts have already been done, how does the same developer that extended the back-end data now make use of it so that he can also output things alongside mine?

Comment: you can add hooks in JavaScript : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325601/what-do-the-args-for-gutenberg-subpackage-hooks-function-doaction-mean/326033#326033

Comment: @Kaperto Splendid! Do you know how can I require `hooks.js` on <5.0 without any conflicts? I searched core for `hooks.js` or any enqueues but can't find where it's enqueued.

Comment: I believe JS hooks were added in 5.0. Updating the site (and activating Classic Editor if you're trying to avoid using the Block Editor) would be safest.